# How does one convert JS, into a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, react-component

First and foremost, sorry for the poor title, StackOverflow had my hands tied. I have some code I found and would like to move into REACT, unfortunately, my skills are limited(for now). Please give me some pointers and tips on how I can translate this (https://codepen.io/brusespinal/pen/VwdjRxY) `May you please visit the codepen`  code javascript code into REACT.js. I have been working on this for some time, and even though I have managed to get the code to compile. It wasn't enough since nothing was rendered, so!!. All the help is welcome.

My goal is to convert this code into a component that can be used as a background.

Comment: As your example is done with canvas, check how to work with it on React, like this https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is precisely what I was looking for. Too bad, the way you answered, makes it impossible to mark the question as answered.

Comment: The best answer if you found yourself in a similar position I was in is on the following website. https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258